# Accessing a model instance from a different model's controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Thread model which has a `show` page, and in that action's view code I have:

```
<%= render 'comments/form' %>
```

---

What is the proper way to initialize the new Comment? I've tried:

- `@comment = @thread.comments.build(params[:comment])` in the Comment create action and the comment form's view code.
- Thread helper methods and Model methods called things like `this_thread`.
- Initializing `@comment` in the Thread's `show` controller code.

All of these attempts led to nil object errors or undefined method errors.

---

In conclusion, which path should I pursue?

---

### Update

To clarify,

- I create a new comment in the Thread controller. `@comment = @thread.comments.build`
- In the comment `create` action, how do I access the @comment I created over in the thread controller?

---

### Update #2

The Comment controller:

```
def create
  thread = Thread.find(params[:id])
  @comment = thread.comments.build(params[:thread])

  if @comment.save
  ...
end
```

is giving me this error:

```
Couldn't find Thread without an ID
```

Do you know why? I'm assuming it has something to do with `params[:id]` being the comment id and not the thread id. How, then, do I get the thread id? Or, what Rails magic am I forgetting to rely on, since this is a `has_many`/`belongs_to` relationship.

Comment: Why are you trying to access an already-created comment in the comment controller's create action? If it's already created, what's left for that action to do?

Comment: rspeicher, The comment is created by `build`, but that only sets the comment's `thread_id`. I still need to fill in the author, title, content, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that `Thread.new` is creating an instance of your model? Ruby has a thread library that also defines a `Thread` class -- you may have a name collision.

> In the comment create action, how do I
>   access the @comment I created over in
>   the thread controller?

Technically, you don't. When your view posts to the Comment controller, a new object has to be created, e.g. `@comment = Comment.new(params[:comment]`. Or if you are retrieving from the DB, `@comment = Comment.find(params[:id]).` Note that `build` does not save the object.

**EDIT**

To get the thread in the controller you have two options. One way is to pass it in as part of the posted form (typically using a hidden field).

A better way is to use nested routes and let Rails do the work for you. If you have a route like:

```
map.resources :spools do |spools|
  spools.resources :comments
end
```

Then in your comments controller you'll get `spool_id` in the params hash. The path will look like so for existing comments:

```
/spools/1/comments/2
```

and like so for new comments

```
/spools/1/comments/
```

Where `params[:spool_id]` is set to 1.

Comment: I changed the model names so they'd be more conventional. My thread model is actually called Spool.

Comment: I'm able to create a comment now, but it doesn't have a `thread_id`. How do I pass the thread id to the Comment controller?

Comment: Thank you, I'm now watching the Railscast on nested resources. This is exactly what I was looking for.